# why does my tab control disappear if I call a page twice in a row?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tabs

I'm trying to switch tabs via buttons and menu options, and it works. But, if you select the same page you're on, all the tabs disappear, never to be seen again. And I'm confused. The same code works on another project without a hitch.

Here's an example:

```
        tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPW);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabSelect);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabMain);
```

When that goes off and you're on another page... great! You go to tabMain. If you're on tabMain and call it, it's time to restart the program.

Comment: Never heard of this going wrong.  Your story doesn't jive well with your snippet, little point in adding the tabMain page twice.  Do keep in mind that Remove() isn't enough, you **must** call the Dispose() method of the tab you remove.  Failure to do so causes an unpluggable handle leak that does make your program go bonkers after a while.

Comment: If it made sense I wouldn't need to ask, haha. Eren offered me a very workable solution, but I'm still a bit confused... as nearly the exact same code works without a hitch on another project of mine, one that I actually use daily, and stays stable for weeks, months at a time. I've never had it do that once in the final build. This one does it EVERY time.

Comment: Don't __Remove__ the Pages, __move__ them, maybe to a List<TabPage>!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to select the tabMain, then just do:

```
 tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabMain;
```

Removing and adding tabs is not a good way for "switching".